# SwiftUI table with default styles crashes (macOS) (Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ListCoreCellHost')

Tags: swiftui-list, swiftui

I am trying to implement a table that follows system style on macOS. There seem to be two ways to do this:

```
struct MyRow: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
}


struct MySection: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var rows: [MyRow]
}
```

1. Iterate via List:

   ```
    List(sections) { section in
        Section(header: Text(section.title)) {
            ForEach(section.rows) { row in
                Text(row.title)
            }
        }
    }
   ```

This works and is stable, but does not apply any formatting. It seems to use stacks under the hood:

[image]

2. Iterate via ForEach

   ```
    List {
        ForEach(sections) { section in
            Section(header: Text(section.title)) {
                ForEach(section.rows) { row in
                    Text(row.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

This is exactly what I want. For some reason, this applies the system styles, has floating group rows etc. - all the things you would expect from a native NSTableView:

[image]

But here is the problem:
It crashes as soon as the order of sections/rows changes at a later point. I assume this is a SwiftUI Bug:

```
**Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ListCoreCellHost' (0x7fff87be7580) to 'SwiftUI.ListCoreHeaderHost' (0x7fff87be75f8).**

**2020-07-05 11:52:00.779004-0700 SwiftUIRepro[47587:1158522] Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.ListCoreCellHost' (0x7fff87be7580) to 'SwiftUI.ListCoreHeaderHost' (0x7fff87be75f8).**
```

I created a repro to demonstrate the bug here: https://github.com/paxos/SwiftUICrashRepro

Also, on macOS 11.16 this doesn't work at all; it just shows empty rows. I assume we are supposed to use the new outline views in the future?

I am bit stuck here. I could use approach 1) and just style everything by myself, but that is usually not what you want to do on macOS.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong here. I am using a similar approach and am seeing the same crash. While I don't have an answer, I'll try your repro project and send feedback to Apple.

Comment: I tried also this. If we have a `List { ForEach { Sections { ForEach { content } } } }` and we try to modify the data of the first ForEach, the app crashes. I sent a feedback to Apple with a sample project.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!!!! We have to add `.id(UUID()` to the `List { ... }` and the app will stop crashing.

```
List {
     ForEach(sections) { section in
         Section(header: Text(section.title)) {
             ForEach(section.rows) { row in
                 Text(row.title)
             }
         }
     }
 }.id(UUID())      <------ THIS
```

Comment: Hi @AlbertUI 
This works fine but can you explain why it is working ?

Comment: Hi @RoshanSah, it works because it will generate a new List in each view cycle, so if the new list have less cells it won't crash (because won't find index out of bounds).
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui